# Add more value to dictionary python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

how do you add value to a key without overwriting the first value? Here is an example of my code:

```
def course_rolls(records):
    """Maps course code to the student ID"""
    course_to_id_dict = {}
    for record in records:
        course = record[0][0]
        student_id = record[1][0]
        course_to_id_dict[course] = {student_id}
    print(course_to_id_dict)
    return course_to_id_dict
records = [(('MTH001', 'Mathematics 1'),
            (2763358, 'Cooper', 'Porter')),
           (('EMT003', 'Mathematical Modelling and Computation'),
            (2788579, 'Mandi', 'Stachowiak'))]
rolls = course_rolls(records)
expected = {'MTH001': {2763358}, 'EMT003': {2788579}}
print(rolls==expected)
```

The output is True

Let's say if a student ID maps with the same key and I wanted the output to be the expected:

```
rolls = course_rolls(records)
records = [(('MTH001', 'Mathematics 1'),
            (2763358, 'Cooper', 'Porter')),
           (('EMT003', 'Mathematical Modelling and Computation'),
            (2788579, 'Mandi', 'Stachowiak')),
           (('MTH001', 'Mathematics 1'),
            (2763567, 'New', 'Value'))]
rolls = course_rolls(records)
expected = {'MTH001': {2763358,2763567}, 'EMT003': {2788579}}
print(rolls==expected)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either detect that the key is already present in `course_to_dict_id` and add to that set, or use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to give you an *empty* set whenever you try to retrieve a key that isn't set yet.

The latter is more concise:

```
for record in records:
    course = record[0][0]
    student_id = record[1][0]
    course_to_id_dict.setdefault(course, set()).add(student_id)
```

This produces `{'MTH001': {2763358, 2763567}, 'EMT003': {2788579}}` as the output (each value in the dictionary a set with 1 or more integers).

Comment: but how come if I wrote course_to_id_dict[course].append({student_id}) would not work

Comment: @AsyrawiAbdullahZawawi: `course_to_id_dict[course]` is not a list, it is a set object (provided the object exists). `course_to_id_dict[course].add(student_id)` would work, provided you first test if `course` is an existing key.